# Can somebody explain why this code does not color every other pixel column in the image red?

Tags: java, pixel, image-manipulation

This code is a test for a larger program I'm building. It is supposed to color every other pixel row in the image red, but the result is the image added below. Can somebody explain why the red isn't showing?

```
package code;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Pixel {

BufferedImage image;
int width;
int height;

public Pixel() throws IOException {
    File input = new File("/Users/SanchitBatra/Desktop/Depixelator.jpg");
    image = ImageIO.read(input);
    width = image.getWidth();
    height = image.getHeight();
}

public void changePixels() throws IOException{

        for(int i=0; i<height; i++){

            for(int j=0; j<width; j++){

                int red;
                //  Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
                if(i%2==0){

                    red = 255;
                }
                else{
                    red=0;
                }
                int green = 0;
                int blue = 0;
                Color newColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

                image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());

            }
        }

        File output = new File("/Users/SanchitBatra/Desktop/grayscale.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", output);

    }


static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Pixel obj = new Pixel();
    obj.changePixels();
}
}
```

This is the resulting image:

[image]

Edit: The program is doing exactly what it should using a coloured image as a source. Thanks to all contributions! I learnt a lot today :)

Comment: by changing the other color values can you get the image to change color at all?

Comment: If I set green and blue to 255 each, alternate rows are colored grey and white hm interesting

Comment: Aside: create your black and red colors outside the loop. No need to create a new instance for each pixel.

Comment: if its not even you are setting to red to 0 and all the others are 0 isnt that black ?

Comment: @AndyTurner I eventually want to be working with individual pixels 

Comment: @EduardoDennis but the image as a whole should not be black, just every other row

Comment: @EduardoDennis When I set it to red = 255, green = 0, and blue = 0 shouldn't it be red?

Comment: I'm starting to think it has something to do with your filename making it greyscale lol

Comment: Hint: your code will become more intuitive to read by renaming `i` to `y` and `j` to `x`

Comment: @CraigR8806   I tried a bunch of stuff because I'm new to the whole pixel manipulation thing and the last thing converted the image to grayscale

Comment: @domdom That is a great idea, and a practice I usually follow except I took this code from a sample program online to test and was too lazy to change

Comment: @Sanchit then learn how to calculate rgb without constructing a `Color`; it's not hard: `0xff << 24 | red << 16 | green << 8 | blue`. This will make your code miles faster.

Comment: Could you show us the resulting image?

Comment: Edited the question :) @domdom

Comment: Huh? That's nothing like what I expected. Didn't you say it is all black? I see several pixel thick gray lines. That's weird.

Comment: Check your source image. Print the color model info : `System.out.println(image.getColorModel());`

Comment: ColorModel: #pixelBits = 8 numComponents = 1 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@79fc0f2f transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false

Comment: It turned everything white

Comment: @domdom In the beginning it WAS completely black then I shifting a few things around and it started alternating but it still wasn't red. Edited the question, my bad

Comment: @SanchitBatra `numComponents = 1` indicates that the source image has only 1 channel.

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the original image only has black color?

Comment: IT WORKED WITH A COLOURED IMAGE!!!

Comment: So we can only write an image using the number of channels we got from it? That's inconvenient :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void changePixels() throws IOException{

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(side,side,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    int[] pixels = new int[width*height];

    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){

        for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
            int colorIn = image.getRGB(j,i);
            int redIn = 255&(colorIn<<16);
            int greenIn = 255&(colorIn<<8);
            int blueIn = 255&(colorIn);

            if(i%2==0){

                redIn = 255;
            }


            pixels[i+j*width] = (255<<24)|(redIn<<16)|(greenIn<<8)|blueIn;



        }
    }
    bi.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
    File output = new File("/Users/SanchitBatra/Desktop/grayscale.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", output);

}
```

I showed you how to pull the color values out using bit shifting here to show you how to have a little bit more control over your process.  This also retains the original pixel values and just overwrites the red value if it is an even column.

Comment: Same result as before *sob*

Answer (score -1):

1. If you want to make columns red, you should make them red along the width instead of the height. The current code will make alternate rows red.
2. I think your code is OK, try to zoom in/out in your image to see if you are getting the desired effects.

Thanks,
Hassaan

Comment: Yes I noticed that too but the major problem is the lack of red 